# DotNet HighCharts Exporting in Web Forms Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, highcharts, webforms

I want to add new button in list of exporting of charts,
i want to perform something like that :
http://jsfiddle.net/3GNZC/189/

but using DotNet HighCharts,
i already Tried to do that:

```
 DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart1")
                            .InitChart(new Chart
                            {
                                BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray,
                                Height = ChartHeight
                            });


chart.SetExporting(new Exporting
            {
                Buttons = new ExportingButtons()
                {
                    ContextButton = new ExportingButtonsContextButton()
                    {
                      MenuItems = **what can i write here!**
                    }
                },
                Enabled = true,
            });
```

my problem here that i can not add new MenuItems to ContextButton  without deleting the options that already exist like(Download PNG Image,....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it's a bug which requires the package developer intervention. I reported it directly to wrapper developer, so we need to wait for the decision. To workaround it, you can temporary paste the code below to your `<script>` tag in `.cshtml`, which adds the button globally to Highcharts object, and bypassing .Net.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

    <script type="text/javascript">

        Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
text: 'Add Issue ',
onclick: function() {
  alert('OK');
}


        function formatXAxis() {
            return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
        }

        function formatYAxis() {
            return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
        }


    </script>   


    @(Html.Highsoft().GetHighcharts(
        new Highcharts
        {
            Title = new Title
            {
                Text = "US and USSR nuclear stockpiles"
            },
            Subtitle = new Subtitle
            {
                Text = "Source: <a href='http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf'>thebulletin.metapress.com</a>"
            },

            XAxis = new List<XAxis>
            {
                new XAxis
                {
                    AllowDecimals = false,
                    Labels = new XAxisLabels
                    {
                        Formatter = "formatXAxis"
                    }

                }
            },
            YAxis = new List<YAxis>
            {
                new YAxis
                {
                    Title = new YAxisTitle
                    {
                        Text = "Nuclear weapon states"
                    },
                    Labels = new YAxisLabels
                    {
                        Formatter = "formatYAxis"
                    }
                }
            },
            Tooltip = new Tooltip
            {
                PointFormat = "{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}"
            },
            PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
            {
                Area = new PlotOptionsArea
                {
                    PointStart = 1940,
                    Marker = new PlotOptionsAreaMarker
                    {
                        Enabled = false,
                        Symbol = "circle",
                        Radius = 2,
                        States = new PlotOptionsAreaMarkerStates
                        {
                            Hover = new PlotOptionsAreaMarkerStatesHover
                            {
                                Enabled = true
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
            Series = new List<Series>
            {
                new AreaSeries
                {
                    Name = "USA",
                    Data = @ViewData["usaData"] as List<AreaSeriesData>

                },
                new AreaSeries
                {
                    Name = "USSR/Russia",
                    Data = @ViewData["russiaData"] as List<AreaSeriesData>
                }
            }
        }
        , "chart")
    )
```